# How to Change MaterialDesignSwitchToggleButton Track Color When IsChecked=True in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, togglebutton

I'm working on a WPF application using the MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit, and I'm trying to customize the appearance of a MaterialDesignSwitchToggleButton. Specifically, I need to change the Track background color when IsChecked is True.

I've attempted to create a Style based on MaterialDesignSwitchToggleButton with a trigger, but it seems to only affect the Thumb color, not the Track.

Here's my current style code:

```
<Style x:Key="ToggleButtonStyle"
       TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignSwitchToggleButton}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
            <!-- Need to change Track color here -->
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

I've attached images for better visualization: [Toggle Actual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2hbv.png), and [Toggle Correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YnBT.png).

Is there a straightforward way to accomplish changing the Track background color when IsChecked is True while maintaining the desired Thumb color?

I've already attempted to change the foreground color without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `ToggleButtonAssist.SwitchTrackOffBackground` and `ToggleButtonAssist.SwitchTrackOnBackground` attached properties to change the colour of the track:

```
<Style x:Key="ToggleButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignSwitchToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="materialDesign:ToggleButtonAssist.SwitchTrackOffBackground" Value="Red" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
            <Setter Property="materialDesign:ToggleButtonAssist.SwitchTrackOnBackground" Value="Green" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```